# Partial Fraction for $x^2/(x^2 +1)^2$

Tags: partial-fractions

$$\begin{aligned}
         \frac{\ x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} \\
      \
      \end{aligned}$$
I am new to partial fractions and this is what I have so far:
$$\begin{aligned}
       \dfrac{(x^2)}{(x+1)^2} = \dfrac A{x-1}+\dfrac B{(x+1)^2}
        \
        \end{aligned}$$

Am I on the right track? I was told it is impossible to take the partial fraction of this but that didn't seem right to me.

Comment: The denominator has $x^2+1$, not $x+1$.

Comment: @NormalHuman I'd been told to not tag things with tags that are not associated with the question, so I kept it to partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}
=\frac{x^2+1-1}{(x^2+1)^2}
=\frac1{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}
$.

If you want to go
into complex numbers,
use
$x^2+1
=(x+i)(x-i)
$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}&=\frac{A}{x^2+1}+\frac{B}{(x^2+1)^2};
\end{align}
you should be able to see what $A$ and $B$ should be.